# SQL Server Maintenance Plans Missing After Creation

Tags: sql-server, ssis, maintenance-plan

When I create new maintenance plans on an instance of SQL 2005 SP2, they are all successfully created (e.g. they are in the Package Store and jobs are created for each step) but they do not show up in the Maintenance Plans folder under Management.

Because of this, I can use them but cannot edit them. I've talked with one other DBA that has seen this but didn't find a resolution for the issue.

Has anyone else experienced this and found a reason for it?

Thanks much!

Clay

Answer (score 0):

Which user are you using to create these maintenance plan?
What is your version of SQL Server?
What does SQL Server returns for these:

```
USE MSDB
SELECT * FROM sysdbmaintplan_databases
SELECT * FROM sysmaintplan_log
SELECT * FROM sysmaintplan_logdetail
SELECT * FROM sysmaintplan_subplans
SELECT * FROM sysmaintplan_plans
```